# Symfony authentication - can't get past login page in production

Tags: authentication, symfony

I've set up Symfony authentication on my local dev server, it works perfectly in both prod and dev environments, today I registered a domain for testing and pushed my code up to an AWS EC2 server, I can get to the login page no problems but as soon as I try to login I get redirected straight back to the login page without any error. It seems as though when it is submitting to login_check it redirects straight back to /login. I've tried clearing and warming the production cache with and without debug, which doesn't seem to solve the problem. There are no errors in my prod.log file.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Thank you.

**Edit:**
This is showing up in the dev log:

```
[2012-03-26 22:52:59] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Your session has    timed-out, or you have disabled cookies. [] []
[2012-03-26 22:52:59] security.DEBUG: Redirecting to /login [] []
```

**Edit** 
Every time I refresh the page I get two new cookies sub.domain.com and .domain.com -- If i look on the server in the /tmp/ dir where the sessions are saved, 6 new sessions are created on each page refresh, the two that are shown in chrome dev tools both have no data inside them. This problem does not exist on my local dev server. Any suggestions on what could be causing this appreciated!!!

**Edit -- Resolution**

I deleted the cookies from Chrome and it suddenly started working. Not sure what the root of the problem was but all seems to be working just fine now.

Comment: See that PHP has sessions set alright. This sounds to me like the server can't write session thus is unable to save you credentials. **ALSO**, try running `dev` mode on that server... dev.log should have plenty of info on what could possible went wrong...

Comment: Could you post your access control or firewall configuration?

Comment: Have you checked logs located in app/logs folder?

Comment: Thanks for the replies - in dev env. I looked in the request profiler and session attributes appear to be set, I took a look in the dev log and found this: [2012-03-26 22:52:59] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Your session has timed-out, or you have disabled cookies. [] []
[2012-03-26 22:52:59] security.DEBUG: Redirecting to /login [] []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it works on your local server so you definitely have cookies enabled. :)

As I said in the comment you should check if session was setup properly in `php.ini`. This includes, among others:

- "session.save_path",
- "session.auto_start".

Also, check in `Firebug` that you have received valid `PHPSESSID` cookie (or anything similar, depending on you `php.ini`). Another thing you might want to check is `config.yml` file for part like this:

```
session:
        default_locale: %locale%
        auto_start:     true
        lifetime:       86400
```

These are all wild guesses but I suspect that "session.save_path" **is not writable** in your filesystem...

Comment: Thanks for this. session.save_path was commented out, i've uncommented and made /tmp 777, it appears to be writing session id's to it. session.auto_start is set to false, if i switch it on I get a symfony error that the session has already started. In chrome I can see the session cookie. I have restarted apache after the changes... hmmmm

Comment: I removed all the session data in the tmp/ dir then refreshed the page. 5 session files were created, I opened the one up that corresponded with the session id in chrome dev tools and it was blank... so the session file is being created but no data is being written to it.

Comment: and on every page refresh six sess_ files are being created in the tmp dir

Comment: Weird. What about `session.use_cookies`, `session.use_only_cookies` and `session.cookie_lifetime` session options? And make sure that `session.cookie_domain` is empty.

Comment: So I finally got it to work, I deleted the two session cookies showing in dev tools and suddenly it started working. I initially had the domain variable set in config to my local host, I wonder if that somehow bugged up the cookie in Chrome even though that was one of the first things I changed. Either way, it seems to be working now so i'm happy - thanks for your help!

Comment: In my case session.auto_start = 1 in my php.ini did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Starting Symfony `2.3` there is a `require_previous_session` setting in the `secure.yml` [configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html), set it to false:

```
    secured_area:
        ...
        form_login:
            ...
            require_previous_session: false
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Tip: Check `config_prod.yml` for subtle configuration differences.

I encountered the same problem while testing the prod environment on my local machine; while I  could authenticate on dev, I couldn't authenticate on prod which gave the error mentioned by the OP:

```
security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Your session has timed-out, or you have disabled cookies. [] []
```

The **disabled cookies** bit got me thinking.

Next I checked the network tab in my browser and peaked at my request/response for the page. I observed that the session cookie was being provided in the server's response, but wasn't being sent by the browser in the request.

Then I had my aha moment:

#### I was using secure cookies on an unencrypted connection

On our production server all unencrypted traffic is redirected to a TLS connection, so it made sense to use [secure cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) in the prod environment; **in config_prod.yml**:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_secure: true
```

The effect is that the session cookie will have `secure` appended to it:

```
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=66117caf467ef2bf8efee373b52449ba; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

conforming browsers/users-agents:

> will not send a cookie with the secure flag set over an unencrypted HTTP request.

The gotchya being that php's native session handling doesn't know or care about the secure flag (it's added by Symfony), so the session cookie can still be sent over an unencrypted connection and the browser (or at least Chrome 35) will — in a baffling fashion — actually use a **secure cookie** received via an insecure/unencrypted connection. I guess it's not that baffling, it's the servers responsibility to invalidate sessions, not the browsers.

**Solution**

I setup *https* on my local machine so I can test the prod environment without futzing with configuration. Enforcing https-only connections only for production kept things simpler for my team, but did trip me up a little.

Take away: higher parity between local and production is usually better!